# SAWarning: Can't resolve label reference 'pettycashfunds.id'; converting to text()

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

cant fix this issue.

I've done searching to some related question and also on the docs but still the problem is still there.

tried:

`PettyCashFundModel.query.order_by(PettyCashFundModel._id.desc()).first()`

**and**

`PettyCashFundModel.query.order_by(desc(PettyCashFundModel._id)).first()`

**and**

`PettyCashFundModel.query.order_by(desc('pettycashfund.id')).first()`

**Model**

` class PettyCashFundModel(db.Model):
    **tablename** = 'pettycashfunds'

```
_id = db.Column('id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)

start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
end_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

check_no = db.Column(db.String(45))

amount = db.Column(db.Float)
total_expenses = db.Column(db.Float)

remaining_money = db.Column(db.Float)

transactions = db.relationship('TransactionModel')
```

`

**error message**

`/home/jay/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/compiler.py:624: SAWarning: Can't resolve label reference 'pettycashfunds.id'; converting to text() (this warning may be suppressed after 10 occurrences)
  util.ellipses_string(element.element))`

Comment: Could you add the error messages you get for each attempt? I think the first one looks like it should work. Could you also include the PettyCashFundModel object code?

Comment: @RachSharp iupdated the question. I got same error for each attempt. yep the first seems right even on the docs and on the other threads, but I still got the same issue

Comment: I think this will require a more complete example. It could be that you haven't created the model in the database (`Base.metadata.create_all(engine)`), but it's hard to tell from separate parts of the code. I would recommend replicating the issue in a new file and adding that complete example, that anyone could run to replicate, to the question

Comment: I had the same issue and it didn't actually affect my application, but it was annoying to see. More information here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/changelog/migration_10.html#order-by-and-group-by-are-special-cases